# Are there commands similar to Ubuntu's 'apt-get clean' and 'apt-get autoremove' in CentOS?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, centos7

I think the title of my question tells it all, but once again, I'm looking for CentOS commands that do the same as those two Ubuntu's:

`sudo apt-get clean`

(removes packages downloaded for installation)

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

(removes packages that are no longer needed, including old kernels).

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/how-to-clear-the-yum-cache/) help?